# parse responseText or change responseText in responseXML

Tags: javascript, xml

ok so my responseText contains an '&' character which seems to cause problems when parsing. so I want to grab my responseText and change the '`&`' for '`&amp;`'

I'm aware responseText is a String and ideally I want to feed this back into the responseXML to parse with the new xml with &

any help much appreciated

```
            responseXML  = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        var myResponseText = "<document-metadata><item><name>ccms_customer_key</name><value>0100000931012004110</value></item><item><name>ccms_customer_name</name><value>Mr Joe Bloggs</value></item><item><name>ccms_customer_salutation_name</name><value>Mr</value></item><item><name>ccms_rm_name</name><value></value></item><item><name>ccms_dms_key</name><value>2432559OEKM</value></item><item><name>ccms_customer_address</name><value>Main & Street Dublin </value></item></document-metadata>";
        /*
        if(myResponseText.indexOf('&') >= 0)    
        {
            var str = myResponseText.replace(/&/g,"&amp;");
            return str;
        }
        */
        //old line getSession().setAttribute('LH_METADATA_XML',xmlhttp.responseText);
        getSession().setAttribute('LH_METADATA_XML',myResponseText);

        // extract COMP_DMS_KEY from metadata
        var root = responseXML.getElementsByTagName('document-metadata').item(0);
```

Comment: This is not a valid XML. Why not fix the code that generates it?

Comment: @llia G because I don't have access to where its generated so this is the hack I'm afraid

Comment: Consider the case where response XML already contains escaped `&amp;`. Your hack will end up double escaping it. Also anyone else reading that response will have exactly the same issue. Also consider that one of the reasons XML exist is so that you *don't* have to do that yourself. So you really should contact whoever has access to that code and tell them to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not parse the string in a completely different way, such as with [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) or (may be what you need due to the error) [`document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument), or even just creating a *HTMLDivElement* and setting `innerHTML`?

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(""); // create a HTML document
doc.body.innerHTML = "<document-metadata><item><name>ccms_customer_key</name><value>0100000931012004110</value></item><item><name>ccms_customer_name</name><value>Mr Joe Bloggs</value></item><item><name>ccms_customer_salutation_name</name><value>Mr</value></item><item><name>ccms_rm_name</name><value></value></item><item><name>ccms_dms_key</name><value>2432559OEKM</value></item><item><name>ccms_customer_address</name><value>Main & Street Dublin </value></item></document-metadata>";
doc.body; // navigate to your root node from here
```

Doing this (i.e. using *text/html* rather than *application/xml*) will mean that the parser is less strict and not be troubled by the `&` whilst retaining the ability to use DOM methods.

From here you can now even re-serialize and convert this to a true XML document, say `root` is your root node

```
var x = new XMLSerializer(), p = new DOMParser(), xml_string, xml_doc;
xml_string = x.serializeToString(root); // now we have a valid string
xml_doc = p.parseFromString(xml_string, 'application/xml'); // and now it is an XML document
```

Comment: I'm presuming doing this way I will eliminate having to replace the & ? Seems a great solution

Comment: @topcat3 Yes. I should point out, though, that if you have nodes that conflict with HTML (e.g. `<head>`) you may find weird behaviour (disappearing nodes, etc) and it's therefore not commonly suggested as "it's a hack not a fix". You could parse immediately with `DOMParser` as `'application/xml'`, but where the parse error happens that particular node will be blank and you will get a `<parsererror>` node as the first child of the root node (at least in Chrome).